# Remove border for Navigation Bar and Toolbar

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having trouble with removing border shadow of UISearchBar, UINavigationBar and UIToolBar. So, basically I have a view controller in which I have embeded a UISearchController and Below that there is a UIToolbar having a UISegmentedControl. The problem is that even after removing border shadows for UINavigationBar, UISearchBar, UIToolbar individually using appearance() delegate, the border still shows up between UISearchBar and UIToolBar.

When I go to next screen I observe that the UINavigationBar doesn't have border shadow, So, it is for sure that the border that is being shown up isn't of UINavigationBar.

I also find out a strange thing, When I hide the UISearchController from UINavigationBar then there is no border between UINavigationBar and UIToolBar. When I hide UIToolBar then also there is no border after the UINavigationBar.

```
extension AppDelegate {

    private func appearanceSetup() {
        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .appBlueColor
        UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.white]
        UITextField.appearance().tintColor = .appBlueColor
        UISearchBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .any, barMetrics: .default)
        UISearchBar.appearance().barTintColor = .appBlueColor
        UISearchBar.appearance().backgroundImage = UIImage()
        UIToolbar.appearance().setShadowImage(UIImage(), forToolbarPosition: .any)
        UIToolbar.appearance().barTintColor = .appBlueColor
        UIToolbar.appearance().layer.borderWidth = 1
        UIToolbar.appearance().layer.borderColor = UIColor.appBlueColor.cgColor
    }
}
```

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {
   private let searchController: UISearchController = {
        let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
        searchController.searchBar.tintColor = .white
        searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = .appBlueColor
        return searchController
    }()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    }
```

[image: Remove border between Search & ToolBar]
[image: Example -> No Border after SearchBar]
[image: Example -> No Border between Nav & ToolBar]

Comment: good question. might be nice to provide a link to a SMALL sample app where we can see the issue / try to take a look

Comment: Here is the demo I just now created, Please clone and have a look at it. https://gitlab.com/rjt3662/borderissue
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setValue(true, forKey: "hidesShadow")
```

try this code I hope it'll solve your problem

Comment: Thank you very much @Habin. Didn't knew this kind of property for navigation bar. I was wondering how this property are being revealed as they aren't available at developer docs?

Comment: you're welcome @RajatMishra. Did your problem solve or not? If solved then please vote and give tick mark so that other could find the answers.

Comment: I have given vote as my problem is solved. But its saying "Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: I mean you have given vote to your question but how do users know which answer is correct for your question so thats why I'm telling you to give vote and tick mark in correct answer. Thank you.

Comment: This solved my problem, so I upvoted! Strange how there is no public function/property for this... which begs the question if it won't break somewhere in the future?

Answer (score 0):

Once i had a similar issue, where the `appeareance`did not resolved my problem. So i proceeded to Customize the Components. I did this for the `UINavigationBar` and it worked, although my `UINavigationBar`was put in the Storyboard, no in code, but it most work anyway. Try this and let me know:

```
class CustomNavigationBar: UINavigationBar
{
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        shadowImage = UIImage()
        backgroundColor = <Your UIView.backgoundColor of type: UIColor>
        tintColor = UIColor.white
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        shadowImage = UIImage()
        backgroundColor = <Your UIView.backgoundColor of type: UIColor>
        tintColor = UIColor.white
    }
}
```

I don't know what is your approach respect to the `UISearchController`, but i had the same issue in the searchBar too, so i added the searchBar in code and use the delegate. The placeholder appear twice, because the versions of iOS, with only one not work fine below iOS 10 or iOS 10+. Depends which one will be removed

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setup()
        installRefresh()
    }

    private func setup() {
        let searchBar = UISearchBar()
        searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = [placeholdetText] // The String for the place holder
        searchBar.searchBarStyle = .default
        searchBar.barTintColor = view.backgroundColor 
        searchBar.placeholder = placeholdetText + ".."
        searchBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .any, barMetrics: .default)
        searchBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        searchBar.delegate = self

        // Extra UI Setup
   }

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        if searchText.isEmpty
        {
            // The filters objects it's what i show after the search, and the 
            // general objects it's all the objects
            filtersObjects = generalObjects
        }
        else
        {
           //... Al the code tu filter from the searchText 
        }
          // Refresh the UI
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back. My approach for using UISearchController is independent. What I mean is that the UISegmentedControl below UISearchController needs to be displayed regardless of the UISearchController. So, using UISearchBar().scopeButtonTitles wouldn't have done the trick because scope buttons are only shown when UISearchController is in active state.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the time to wrote. I will send you some points to your question. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //MARK:- for default navigation bar

        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: " ", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.white

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for:.default)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layoutIfNeeded()

    }
```

Comment: If you are answering a question , please try to give a short description about your answer. refer here, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

```
    //MARK:- for default navigation bar

    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: " ", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.white

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for:.default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layoutIfNeeded()

}
```